# Auth0client not found on xamarin studio under components

Tags: xamarin, auth0, xamarin.mac

I am creating Desktop Application for MAC. In which i am trying to use Auth0Client for authentication using instagram but unable to find this component on xamarin studio under get more components.

Answer (score 2):

The Auth0Client from the Xamarin Component store is only available for iOS and Android applications.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I checked alot of components under xamarin studio. it shows all listing of supporting IOS, Android and windows. Also, Auth0Client supports these three. I haven't find any icon for OS X on the listing of all the components under XAMARIN STUDIO. Is there any alternative to use this? I want to add authentication for instagram users